# SQL Server Database Mail failing to send emails with error Sender address rejected: Access denied

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

The environment is a 2 node 2008 SQL Cluster.  The first node was running fine but after failover to the second node Database Mail no longer can send emails.  I am using Basic authentication.

The full error message is: The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 0 (2012-04-10T15:26:56). Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (Transaction failed. The server response was: 5.7.1 : Sender address rejected: Access denied). )

This appears to be a SMTP issue but I have validated it is not by writing a vbscript with CDO using the same credentials as Database Mail configuration and the emails go through fine on the same box.

I have recreated the Database Mail account on the second node just to make sure the credentials are correct but that didn't fix the problem.

Does anyone know how to get this working again?

Comment: Sounds like SMTP credentials have changed.  Have you verified this?

Comment: Yes, I verified the credentials have not changed.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the IP of your second node is not allowed to [relay](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304897).

Comment: I was thinking the same thing at first but the smtp server I am connecting to is at Rackspace and they don't have any IP limitations that I know of.  Also doesn't the fact that I can send email with CDO from the second node prove that the problem is not with the SMTP server?

Comment: Can you confirm w your Exchange admin that both nodes' public IPs are allowed to relay? Can you fail back to the other node and see if it still works there?

Comment: Creating maintenance window tonight to patch cluster and do failover.

Comment: Great, let us know how it goes.

Comment: After patching and failover testing node 1 works and node 2 does not.  Our email is provided by Rackspace (Pop3, no exchange) so I am connecting to their smtp server directly in my config.  I used telnet to test smtp auth and sending message and it works from both nodes.  It seems like node 2 is not passing the credentials properly.

Comment: Yes confined to node 2, so that's good to know. I'd ask them if the IP of the 2nd node is set up for relay. It could be a simple fix.

Comment: Both nodes use the same external IP address so I don't think it can be a relay issue (the nodes are internal to our network and our email provider is external).